# Creating a Stacked Column graph

Tags: macos, vba, excel

So I've seen a couple posts on this topic, but can't seem to find a way to get it to work. My goal is to create a Stacked Column Graph using VBA with the following characteristics:

1. Each column is based on data from a row (e.g. `E6:P6`, `E7:P7`, etc.).
2. Each "stack section" is each column in that row (located at `E4:P4`)
3. X Axes Labels are located in column A (e.g. `A6`, `A7`, etc.)
4. Y Axes Labels dynamic based on data (non specific).
5. Chart Title (which is the easy part - I got this).

Granted I also need the legend which shows the color key used by item 2.

This graph is one of three needed per report across 30+ reports that I generated via VBA from a raw data file. The last step to the reports is to make these graphs.
I am able to get stacked graph created, but the biggest problem is that as the data ranges above show, there are gaps in the data. This causes split sections in the graph as well as additional labels that I don't want. Essentially I don't know how to format the graph, and reading the Object Window that pops up from typing "ActiveChart." has only gotten me this far. If I know various formatting commands (alas I'm new to VBA with Excel), I can replicate it across all the charts that I need.

```
Dim data As Range
Set data = Range("A4:P12")
With Charts.Add
     .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
     .SetSourceData Source:=data, PlotBy:=xlColumns
     .HasTitle = True
     .ChartTitle.Text = "Weekly Report"
     .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
End With
```

Example of what I can make: 
[Output Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LHIm.png)

Side note about the blank data: The leftmost blank spot where a bar would be is the empty column D. Also I need to be able to edit the axes labels.

Comment: The macro recorder is usually a great tool for figuring out these API's.

Comment: This looks like: "I want someone to develop a solution for me" sort of question, which are generally frowned upon here unless they're extraordinarily simple (i.e., obvious runtime error, etc.).  Consider providing your VBA code attempts, and indicate *specific* problems you're encountering, not just "show me how to do the full-blown solution".  Cheers.

Comment: @DavidZemens Sorry, I figured for the meager amount of code it takes, that it wouldn't be worth seeing what I failed on. I'll post it up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Public Sub MakeGraph()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim data As Excel.Range
    Dim x_axis_labels As Excel.Range
    Dim series_names As Excel.Range
    Dim sh As Excel.Shape
    Dim ch As Excel.Chart
    Dim I As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set data = ws.Range("E4:P12")   ' Assumes the data are in E4:P12
    Set x_axis_labels = ws.Range("A4:A12")  ' Assumes the labels are in A4:A12
    Set series_names = ws.Range("E2:P2")  ' Assumes the labels are in E2:P2
    Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart
    Set ch = sh.Chart
    With ch
         .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
         .SetSourceData Source:=data, PlotBy:=xlColumns
         .HasTitle = True
         .ChartTitle.Text = "Weekly Report"
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryNames = x_axis_labels

         ' Add series names
         For I = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            .SeriesCollection(I).Name = series_names.Cells(1, I)
         Next I
    End With

    Set ch = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
    Set series_names = Nothing
    Set x_axis_labels = Nothing
    Set data = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Awesome, that answered all of my fundamental questions and I was able to manipulate the ranges to where my data is. The main thing I was failing on then was the Axes Names, because I could get Series Collection to work, but couldn't get all the data and still get Axes without messing it up.  However, I do have a couple of questions regarding the solution so I understand it for the future. Why use the Shape/Chart objects instead of just Add.Chart, what benefit do they have? Why set everything to Nothing at the end? Is there a property that modifies the order of the Series or Columns themselves?

Comment: @S. Cannon. **Re Shape/Chart vs Add.Chart**: either way should work fine --- it's mostly a question of style. **Re setting Objects to Nothing**: VBA is supposed to do that automatically, but several years ago I had a VBA project with lots of objects that exhibited eratic behavior. Things stabilized when I cleaned up my objects, so I've been doing it ever since (probably over-cautious).

Comment: @S. Cannon. **Re Series Order**: There are at least 3 ways to do this.     1. Use the Series.PlotOrder property to re-order the series.  2. Instead of .SetSourceData which adds all the series at once, you could use SeriesCollection.Add and add the series one at a time in your preferred order.  3. You could sort the data to a preferred order before making the graph. It may also be possible to re-order the items in the Legend, but I've never tried that.

Comment: I looked up the API for SeriesCollection.Add and I can see how it can be done! Thanks for all the help.

Comment: So I ran into a problem. Some of the columns of data are empty (correctly empty). However, while the graph correctly plots all the values of the data in the range, it assigns them incorrectly. For example, Say E4-P4 are series names. E6-P6 is one set of data. E6 is empty. It correctly plots values in F6-P6, but using only the first 11 labels (E4:O4), instead of the correct labels (F4:P4), basically it assigns the empty header E4 to the first column with data, and continues from there. I tried using .DisplayBlanksAs = xlNotPlotted, but that didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Manage to be sneaky and create an array which iterated and found empty columns. Then surrounded the SeriesCollection.Name block with it to only add series names that had data. Now the only problem comes with adding additional series to the chart each time I need to update the chart for a new week's data. I'd rather update than delete and remake (for efficiency). I'm getting a lot of bugs with SeriesCollection.Add, primarily it not finding previous Series name schemes. Charts seem way more difficult in VBA compared to other things I've done that seem like they should be harder but arent

Comment: I'm not clear on what problems you're now encountering. Would it make sense to ask a new question? That might clarify what's working, what's not working, why updating with new data is hard, the buggy behavior you're seeing with adding new series, etc.

Comment: A new questions seems a bit overkill. Essentially I just want to be edit the graphs range of data after it has already been set. So in a later macro it will run, append one line of data to the source, and then the graph will need to recalculate it's source data.

Answer (score 0):

I take it your missing data would be a column in the range E6:P14? (I'm using E6:P14 because that's what you said first. Your code and @xidgel's later said E4:P12.)

Try this:

```
Sub MakeChart()
  Dim rCats As Range
  Dim rNames As Range
  Dim rData As Range
  Dim iCol As Long

  Set rCats = ActiveSheet.Range("A6:A14")
  Set rNames = ActiveSheet.Range("E4:P4")
  Set rData = ActiveSheet.Range("E6:P14")

  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnStacked).Chart
    Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
      .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop

    For iCol = 1 To rData.Columns.Count
      If WorksheetFunction.Count(rData.Columns(iCol)) > 0 Then
        ' it's not blank
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
          .Values = rData.Columns(iCol)
          .XValues = rCats
          .Name = "=" & rNames.Cells(1, iCol).Address(, , , True)
        End With
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```